# Maya python and camera animation

Tags: python, animation, camera, maya

Hey so in maya using python I am importing cameras that are locked with keyed animation on them and I just wanted the timeslider at the bottom to update to the length of animation of the imported camera. I can get the timeslider to adjust I am just having trouble finding the keyframe to adjust it to through python.

(example: I import 4 cameras. 1 camera is 10 keyframes. 2 and 3 are 15 keyframes. and then 4th is 52. So I want the timeslider to be 1-52. I can get it to move but i dont know how to find the number 52)

edit: sorry basically I import my camera

```
cams = [cam1,cam2,cam3,cam4]
```

for x of cams:

```
cmds.file(x, i=True, dns=True, rnn = True) #i for import

 # this is how i change the timeslider but I want it to
 # be the number of keyframed animation on the camera
cmds.playbackOptions(max=1000)
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code that sets the timeslider and has a camera object to work from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
camera = 'Camera1'
channel = 'translateX'
keyframes = cmds.keyframe('{}.{}'.format(camera, channel), query=True)
first, last = keyframes[0], keyframes[-1]
cmds.playbackOptions(min=first, max=last, ast=first, aet=last)
```

This works regardless of whether or not the channels are locked.

Comment: dude this worked perfect just had to add a "{0}.{1}" in between the brackets because I think I'm in an older version of python. Thank You!

Comment: wonderful! yes, the `{}` syntax requires python 2.7, which was only included with Maya 2014. Earlier versions use python 2.6

Comment: So I had to use cmds.keyframe('{0}.{1}'.format(camera, channel), query=True)... This wont work on a locked camera. Any ideas? I get error = # TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable #

Comment: does it have keyframes? maya has a terrible tendency to return `None` instead of an empty list. You'll have to check `if keyframes` before continuing

Comment: @cjaxx, I *did* test a maya camera with locked keys. it returned a list of frames